# Getting a percent value in a string

Tags: java, android, regex

Im working with ping in android.  and i got this stirng :

```
String mystring =3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2003ms;
```

i need the 100% in string . how can i get this?

y try using this

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[\\d%]*\\d[\\d%]*");
            Matcher mm = pat.matcher(mystring);

if (mm.find()) {    
    String result=  mm.group();
    Log.e("Expresion", result);
}
```

the output is the

```
03-06 17:54:25.787: E/Expresion(21576): 3
```

any idea to obtain only the 100% .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about?

```
private static final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+%");
```